# Laravel 6 Artisan make traits custom command not working

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a trait using php artisan command but have no idea why it is not working.

> app/Console/Stubs/trait.stub

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait DummyTrait
{

}
```

> app/Console/Commands/TraitMakeCommand.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use function app_path;

class TraitMakeCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:trait {name : Traits name you want to use.}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new trait';

    /**
     * The type of class being generated.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = 'Trait';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        return $this->getStub();
    }

    /**
     * Get the stub file for the generator.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return app_path('Console/Stubs/trait.stub');
    }

    /**
     * Get the default namespace for the class.
     *
     * @param string $rootNamespace
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace . '\Traits';
    }
}
```

> app/Console/Kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    ...

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\TraitMakeCommand::class,
    ];

    ...
}
```

> Artisan output for: `pa make:trait -h`

```
Description:
  Create a new trait

Usage:
  make:trait <name>

Arguments:
  name                  Traits name you want to use.

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

Comment: what happens when you call it?

Comment: It runs the command without error but outputs nothing. I mean not creating a Trait file under app/Traits/ folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GeneratorCommand` to generate files for stubs. This base class implements most of the logic. All the custom settings can be achieved by overriding some methods. Checkout the example below:

> app/Console/Commands/TraitMakeCommand.php

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;

class TraitMakeCommand extends GeneratorCommand
{
    protected $name = 'make:trait';
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new trait';
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:trait {name : Traits name you want to use.}';


    /**
     * The type of class being generated.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = 'Trait';

    /**
     * Get the stub file for the generator.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return app_path('Console/Stubs/trait.stub');
    }


    /**
     * Get the default namespace for the class.
     *
     * @param string $rootNamespace
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace . '\Traits';
    }
}
```

and update the stub:

> app\Console\Stubs\trait.stub

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait DummyClass
{

}
```

and then the usage would be:

```
php artisan make:trait Example
```

which would result in the file: `app/Traits/Example.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait Example
{

}
```

Comment: Great. done the job. One thing. It is setting up file name as given name but not the Trait name/. Any idea?

Comment: Referring MakeControllerCommand I have figured out renaming the file and trait name. Thanks for your help.