# Creating my custom classes with Laravel Artisan [Laravel 8]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a command that generates a class in the Services directory using the `make:service` command in Laravel 8. I followed the steps of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240447/laravel-6-artisan-make-traits-custom-command-not-working).

```php
class ServiceMakeCommand extends GeneratorCommand
{
    protected $name = 'make:service';
    protected $signature = 'make:service {name: Create your own service}';
    protected $description = 'Create a service for repository pattern';
    protected $type = 'Service';

    protected function getStub()
    {
        return app_path('Console/Stubs/service.stub');
    }

    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace . '\Services';
    }
}
```

Also, I create my template stub.

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class DummyClass
{

}
```

But I get this error when I try to run this command.

```
php artisan make:service ProductService
```

**Error**

> The "name" argument does not exist.

What does it mean?

Comment: Make sure there's a space between `name` and `:` in `signature`: `protected $signature = 'make:service {name : Create your own service}';`

Comment: What if you drop `$signature`? I went through some `extend GeneratorCommand` classes in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console` and none have a signature.